# Is it possible to do mathematical operations on values in the same column but different rows?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Say I have this table,

```
 year |     name      | score
------+---------------+----------
 2017 | BRAD          |   5
 2017 | BOB           |   5
 2016 | JON           |   6
 2016 | GUYTA         |   2
 2015 | PAC           |   2
 2015 | ZAC           |   0
```

How would I go about averaging the scores by year and then getting the difference between years?

```
 year |  increase
------+-----------
 2017 | 1
 2016 | 3
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I made some changes/edits; sorry about the question earlier (first time using stack and didn't realize my question was extremely unclear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), `lead()` in this case:

```
select year, avg, (avg - lead(avg) over w)::int as increase
from (
    select year, avg(score)::int
    from my_table
    group by 1
    ) s
window w as (order by year desc);

 year | avg | increase 
------+-----+----------
 2017 |   5 |        1
 2016 |   4 |        3
 2015 |   1 |         
(3 rows)
```

Comment: this is very helpful (I simplified the data a bit but this works well for my original set), thank you so much!

Comment: this might be a silly question but what is the s at the end of the from() statement?

Comment: A subquery in FROM must have an alias - this `s` is an alias.